# how to log in to my mail in gmail on click(providing username and password) using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

Hi all i am working on c# .net i need to log in to my mail (gmail) on a click

i am providing username and password but still it's not logged in. is there any way to log in? may be i am doing some thing wrong. is this is the way to login? thanks in advance

below is my link

```
Main Application
Welcome saddudatu to Main Application.
link to login




<div id="divLinks"><a href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&amp;passive=true&amp;rm=false&amp;continue=http://mail.google.com/mail/&amp;scc=1&amp;ltmpl=default&amp;ltmplcache=2&amp;emr=1


?UserId=saddudatu@gmail.com & password="password">link to login</a><br></div>
```

above i am providing username and password

Comment: I'm not sure google allows you to access gmail outside. At least not this way. Consider to use GoogleAPI to access different google services from outside.

Comment: thanks for replay Andras Sebo is this the right way to login is any other site allows to login like fb or twitter r else pleasw let me know thanks

Comment: I think you just want to allow users to login with their existing google accounts. if yes then you can use the **openId authentication**

Comment: yes sachin exactly i want to allow users to login with their existing google accounts only i don't hve any idea could you share me some links thanks for reply ""openId authentication""

Comment: @Sadda-shutu you can start from here http://dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: thanks for replay Sachin